# ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property 'switchToHttp' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchToHttp' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, logging, nestjs, typeorm

**what I am trying to do?**
I am trying to implement a logger to log queries from TypeOrm and also add some information to the logs to identify the user

**how I am trying to achieve this?**
I have implemented the Logger interface from TypeOrm and used Winston for logging.
To identify the user I want to extract the JWT token for the particular request that is executing the query, from which I will have the user.id key.

To get the JWT I am using the ExecutionContext class provided by NestJs to get the request body and then extract the JWT token.

**what issue I am facing?**
I have given the implementation below and the error for it, I can see that the execution context is undefined and I am not sure how to pass the value to it, I am new to nest, and if I am not wrong, nest takes cares of the assignment of the ExecutionContext class.

Also, I am open to suggestions to implement it in a different way.

The Error:

```
[Nest] 11968  -  ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (9)...
TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchToHttp' of undefined
```

The Implementation:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import { ExecutionContext  } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Logger, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
import { createLogger, Logger as winstonLogger, transports, format } from 'winston';
import { Format } from 'LogForm';
import { Request } from 'express';

export class CustomLogger implements Logger {
    
    private readonly queryLogger: winstonLogger;
    private readonly winstonFormat: Format;
    private readonly ctt: ExecutionContext;

    healthcheck2(ctx: ExecutionContext): any {
        const payload = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();
        console.log(payload);
    }
    
    constructor(){
        this.winstonFormat= format.printf(({message})=> {
            return `${message}`
        });
        
        const options = (filename: string) => ({
            transports: [new transports.Console({level:'debug'})],
            format: this.winstonFormat      
        });

        this.queryLogger = createLogger(options('query.log'))
    }
    logQuery(query: string, _parameters?: any[], _queryRunner?: QueryRunner) {
        
       this.healthcheck2(this.ctt);

        this.queryLogger.log({
            level: 'debug',
            message: 'query logged',
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            label: 'query'
        })
    }
    logQueryError(error: string | Error, query: string, parameters?: any[], queryRunner?: QueryRunner) {
        console.log('query error');
    }
    logQuerySlow(time: number, query: string, parameters?: any[], queryRunner?: QueryRunner) {
        console.log('other error');
    }
    logSchemaBuild(message: string, queryRunner?: QueryRunner) {
        console.log('schema build');
    }
    logMigration(message: string, queryRunner?: QueryRunner) {
        console.log('other error');
    }
    log(level: 'log' | 'info' | 'warn', message: any, queryRunner?: QueryRunner) {
        console.log('normal log')
    }
    
}
```